# Tratamento de erros de foreign key no Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou implementando um código onde tem uma chave estrangeira em duas tabelas. Logo já tentei diversos meios e não conseguir tratar o erro:

```
Error Number: 1451

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`base`.`tableus`, CONSTRAINT `doctor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`department_id`))

DELETE FROM `department` WHERE `department_id` = '1'

Filename: models/Crud.php

Line Number: 292
```

Ja usei um exempo que encontrei [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463429/codeigniter-foreign-key-constraint-check) e não resolveu.

Eu revendo minha dúvida aqui, deixei passar um detalhe importante, eu não quero que o usuário apague os dados da tabela 'pai' enquanto tiver tabelas 'filhas' vinculadas a ela. Toda vez que o usuário tentar fazer isso ele deve receber um erro, no caso eu não to conseguindo é tratar esse erro no codeigniter.

```
    function delete_department($department_id)
{
  //verifica se recebe mensagem de erro na exclusão.

    $verifica_erro = $this->db->_error_number() == 1451;
    if ($this->delete_department($department_id) == $verifica_erro){
        echo "Mensagem de erro para o usuário!";
    }else{ 

 //senão tiver executa a exclusão.
        $this->db->where('department_id',$department_id);
        $this->db->delete('department');
    }
}
```

Esse código executa e tras um outro erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in /Path/system/core/Common.php on line 658 and defined in /Path/system/core/Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0 /Path/system/core/Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown in /Path/system/core/Exceptions.php on line 190

Comment: Isso não é com _CodeIgniter_. **Esse erro vem do banco**. Você está tentando apagar ou atualizar um registro na tabela pai que possui referências em outra tabela com uso de FK. Mexa na configuração do seu banco e configure os registros para serem apagados/atualizados junto com o principal.

Comment: Certo, mais no caso foi eu mesmo que criei essa FK, para proteger a integridade dos dados.
Eu preciso tratar esse erro no codeigniter, ou seja para quando o usuário tentar deletar um departamento que esta sendo usado receba uma mensagem personalizada e não o erro acima.
Eu não to conseguindo criar essa função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois da edição a pergunta ficou mais clara, e a resposta é simples: **não tem como tratar esse erro da forma que vc quer**. Da forma que vc faz o erro **já está sendo tratado**.

Pense: existe uma *FK*, e ela está fazendo o trabalho dela. Então, se vc tentar excluir ou atualizar um registro *parent* sem usar *CASCADE*, **você vai receber o erro**, e isso não tem como evitar no *PHP*, porque acontece no banco, e o *CodeIgniter* não tem como evitar que erros aconteçam no banco. No máximo ele vai te dar um aviso quando acontecerem, e é isso que ele está fazendo.

**Porém**, é possível testar os registros *antes de executar a tentativa de exclusão*, e isso é simples:

Considere que `parent` é sua tabela principal, e que `child` é sua tabela que tem o registro `parent_id` relacionado.

```
function delete($id = NULL){
        $query = "DELETE FROM parent WHERE id = '$id';";
        # The cat's leap: teste as tabelas antes de tentar excluir o principal
        $this->db->where('parent_id', $id);
        $test = $this->db->get('child');
        if(empty($test->result_array())){
            echo 'execute $query';
            //$this->db->query($query);
        } 
        else {
            echo 'show some error';
        }
}
```

Isso tudo só porque vc não quer usar *CASCADE*.

Comment: Muito obrigado deu certo aqui o código.
Eu testei aqui a função CASCADE no banco, ele não atende o que eu preciso, pois ele deleta a linha pai e as linhs filhas. E no caso não pode ocorrer, pois se um usuário executa algo acidental pode fazer um estrago no sistema.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é um problema com a configuração do seu banco. Modelagem é algo importante pra evitar essas coisas. Isso e conhecer a documentação da aplicação.

O MySQL faz isso pra evitar que a integridade dos dados seja comprometida , ou seja, pra evitar que vc altere um registro principal e faça todas as outras referências a este registro ficarem perdidas. Veja, a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) diz (em tradução livre):

> Quando uma operação UPDATE ou DELETE afeta um valor de chave na tabela pai que tem linhas correspondentes na tabela filho, o resultado depende da ação referencial especificada usando as subcláusulas ON UPDATE e ON DELETE da cláusula FOREIGN KEY. O MySQL suporta cinco opções sobre a ação a ser tomada, listadas aqui:

Basicamente, vc tem que dizer pro banco pra remover/atualizar automaticamente nas tabelas filho os registros apagados/atualizados na tabela principal. Pra isso vc deve usar `CASCADE`, como vimos acima:

> CASCADE: Exclua ou atualize a linha da tabela pai e exclua ou atualize automaticamente as linhas correspondentes na tabela filho. Ambos ON DELETE CASCADE e ON UPDATE CASCADE são suportados. Entre duas tabelas, não definir várias cláusulas ON UPDATE CASCADE que agem na mesma coluna na tabela pai ou na tabela filho.

Um exemplo de  relacionamento com exclusão/atualização automática de referências

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Viu `ON DELETE CASCADE` e `ON UPDATE CASCADE`? Pois é. Essa configuração na tabela evita esse erro que vc está vendo. Assim, quando o `id` for alterado/apagado na tabela `parent`, `parent_id` será automaticamente alterado e apagado nas tabelas filho.

**Atenção:** usando CASCADE é um bom hábito fazer cópia dos registros antes de deletar/atualizar. Assim, caso seja necessário, será possível recuperar os dados para conferência.

Comment: Isso, modelagem é super importante. É bom modelar bem o banco antes de usá-lo! Para evitar ter que ficar fazendo alterações nas tabelas! Ótima resposta.

Comment: Entendi seu raciocínio, mais no caso justamente eu não que quero que o usuário exclua os dados da tabela parete se ela estiver vinculada a outro cadastro, só faça isso quando não tiver mais nada vinculado a ela. Ai eu quero tratar esse erro que vem do banco para o codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

Você primeiro tem que deletar o outro registro da tabela da qual essa tabela está referenciando através da chave estrangeira.

Comment: Na minha opinião não é tão simples. Apagar o registro na tabela principal vai deixar um monte de outros registros órfãos.

Comment: Coloque um diagrama das tabelas se possível.

Comment: E isso mesmo, mais quem vai fazer isso é o usuário final, ou seja se ele for apagar um departamento e esse estiver com algum funcionário cadastrado vai dar o erro, e é o que quero tratar.